# 24 теста из 25 проходят. 1 не проходит по времени (3 секунды). Как ускорить программу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, реализация

В этой задаче от вас потребуется написать программу для составления расписания сеансов связи со спутником. Каждый сеанс заключается в обмене короткими сообщениями, поэтому мы считаем, что он происходит мгновенно. Поскольку ресурсы оборудования ограничены, следует стремиться к минимизации количества сеансов. Вместе с тем, интервал времени между сеансами не должен превышать `d` миллисекунд. Кроме того, существуют промежутки времени, в течении которых связь  невозможна. При этом на границах промежутка мгновенный сеанс связи возможен. Расписание составляется на `t` миллисекунд. Первый сеанс должен обязательно состояться в момент 0, а последний —  в момент `t`.

В первой строке через пробел записаны три натуральных числа `a`, `d` и `t` — количество интервалов недоступности связи, максимальный интервал между между сеансами и время, на которое составляется расписание. Далее в `a` строках заданы по два целых неотрицательных числа `n` и `k` — начало и конец каждого интервала недоступности связи.

```
Пример ввода:
3 20 100
5 25
27 40
75 90

Пример вывода:
8
```

Мой код:

```
a, d, t = map(int, input().split())
kol = 0
mil = 0
for i in range(a):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    while mil <= n:
        kol += 1
        mil += d
    if mil >= k:
        continue
    else:
        kol += 1
        mil = n + d
while mil < t:
    kol += 1
    mil += d
kol += 1
print(kol)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

зачем вы делаете циклы?

```
while mil < t:
    kol += 1
    mil += d
```

когда это делается в 1 деление:

```
kol += 1 if t < mil else (1 + (t - mil) // d)
mil += 0 if t < mil else d * ((t - mil) // d)
```

это же быстрее

и в коде выше тоже самое

P.S.

правильность логики я не смотрел, только отмечаю, что не надо гонять циклы там где им не место